# mdx query - merging two queries to one

Tags: mdx, multidimensional-array, mondrian

I'm using Mondrian and I have this query (Let's call it [query A]):

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Games].[**Some Game Name**]})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Users].[User Name].Members})} ON ROWS
FROM [Games_G]
```

Which returns me a list of users who are fan of a game given, and within the users returned from [query A] I have to run [query B]:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Games].[Game Name].Members})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Fans]})} ON ROWS
FROM [Games_G]
WHERE {Hierarchize({{[Users].[**Some Username**], [Users].[**Some UsernameTwo**], [Users].[**Some UsernameThree**], etc}})}
```

How can I merge between the two queries?
Thanks in advance and sorry for being a mdx-query-noob.

Comment: I want to use one query instead of two. The goal of the query - get the list of the games that have the same fans (and the number of fans) with game X ("Some Game Name" as written in query A.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that one using the [NonEmpty](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/NonEmpty.html) function:

```
SELECT

   NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Games].[Game Name].Members})} ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Fans]})} ON ROWS

FROM ( SELECT 

  NonEmpty( 
     [Users].[User Name].Members, 
     ( [Games].[**Some Game Name**] , [Measures].[Fans] )
  ) on 0 

  FROM [Games_G]

)
```

[edit] sub-query does not seem supported by Mondrian

Comment: Hey, I've tried: 
SELECT
   NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Games].[Game Name].Members})} ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Fans]})} ON ROWS
FROM [Games_G]
WHERE {Hierarchize({[Users].[User Name].Members, ([Games].[One], [Measures].[Fans])})}
But it gives me an error: 
MondrianException: Mondrian Error:All arguments to function '{}' must have same hierarchy.

Comment: This is not the code I've written at all ? You've written WHERE {Hierarchize( .... => this should be FROM ( SELECT ...

Comment: Hey, your query fits the icCibe system, but I'm using Saiku. Your query gives me also an error.

Comment: Would be helpful to have the error message otherwise cannot help you. Your previous comment is about an error generated by a query that I've not proposed.

Comment: MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Syntax error at line 6, column 6, token '('. 


Line 6:"FROM ( SELECT"

Comment: Sorry - it seems subquery are not supported in Mondrian. I've edited the question and response to mention this is for Mondrian.